# Getting error while using Json Array in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, wcf

I am calling my WCF webservice which basically Serializing my Class and returing JSON using Newtonsoft.

Following is my JSON response which i am trying to use in AngularJS.

```
[{"OptionListId":{"Options":[{"OptionId":1,"OptionName":"Yes","IsActive":true},{"OptionId":2,"OptionName":"No","IsActive":true}],"OptionListId":1,"OptionListName":"YesNo","IsActive":true},"QuestionId":2,"QuestionName":"What is your name?","QuestionType":"text","ShortText":"Short Data","IsActive":true,"GroupsList":null}]
```

I have assigned it to $scope.data.

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:52626/Service1.svc/GetQuestions").then(function (response) {
   $scope.data = angular.fromJson(response.data);
   console.log($scope.data);
   });
```

Now when i am trying to use it inside ng-repeat it is not working.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="d in data">
        <label>{{d}}</label>
    </div>
```

Error which is showing in browser is as per following.
[image]

Error: angular.js:9778 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: try `<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="d in data track by $index"> `

Comment: @IARKI error gone, but can not access any key.. and all data is printed like every character in new line.

Comment: the questions is: What do you want to display? If you want to display 'QuestionName' you should do `<label>{{d.QuestionName}}</label>`

Comment: What you want to display?

Comment: Basically, I want to display question name. Then based on its type I want to bind either input or select or radio button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake i was doing was, i need to do angular.fromJson first to serialize it. and then i needed it to parse using JSON.parse for making it Json Object.

Rest of the things are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat="d in data track by $index"`. If you didn't use track by $index, It will throw the error because of duplicates. Even you can't push in to the data if you didn't mention track by $index.

Comment: When i directly copy paste the response JSON into $scope.data. There is no any error. but when assigning from $http.get response, it is showing error. why?

Comment: $index is printing 320 lines... every character in new line.

Comment: Thats not the problem. put your all JSON data. So, I can help you out

Comment: There is no `response.data` data property to the response object. But you are doing like `response.data`. That might be the problem